# Facebook URL scheme to post on a page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

Is it possible to post on a page with a url scheme?

I currently have this, fb://profile/325899700848032

But this only opens the page ofcourse. What i mean is something like this
fb://profile/325899700848032/PostMessage/"test message" or ../PostImage/image

Is anything like this possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to do this with the Facebook Graph API. See here to get started: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post on facebook page you need to ask first for the famous `manage_pages` authorization. Once you have it you make a FBRequest on the openGraph for `me/accounts` which return an array of the current user pages and other application. You parse this json for each page and you pick the `token_access` and the `id`. You then set the page token access on your facebook manager and then you can post for example a picture to the page with the `"{id}/photos"` POST graph request `{id}` being the page id.